# SAX parser in java and values for integer

Tags: java, xml

I have used  script below  and the output is
X value : 123
Y value : 123
X value : 123
Y value : 130

how can I  set  first X as X0; first Y as Y0 and second X as X1 and second Y as Y1 ? I used SAX parser,  it has processed my input file properly, and now i want to define  X0, X1, Y0, Y1 in order to draw line

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {

        try {

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

        boolean xele = false;
        boolean yele = false;


        public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                    Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
                xele = true;
            }

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                yele = true;
            }


        }
        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

            if (xele) {
                System.out.println("X value : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                xele = false;
            }

            if (yele) {
                System.out.println("Y value : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                yele = false;
            }


        }

         };

           saxParser.parse("c:\\input.xml", handler);

         } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare arrays to hold the values of X and Y and an index to increment after storing the values every time `characters` method is called by the parser, in your DefaultHandler implementation and expose these arrays through getters. Alternatively, you can use collections like `java.util.List`/`java.util.ArrayList` to hold the values.

```
public static void main(String argv[])
{
    try
    {

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        MyDefaultHandler handler = new MyDefaultHandler();
        saxParser.parse("c:\\input.xml", handler);
        System.out.println(handler.getXList() + ", " + handler.getYList());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static class MyDefaultHandler extends DefaultHandler
{
    private List<Integer> xList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private List<Integer> yList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean xele = false;
    boolean yele = false;

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
    {

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("X"))
        {
            xele = true;
        }

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            yele = true;
        }

    }

    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException
    {

        if (xele)
        {
            System.out.println("X value : " + new String(ch, start, length));
            xele = false;
            xList.add(Integer.parseInt(new String(ch, start, length)));
        }

        if (yele)
        {
            System.out.println("Y value : " + new String(ch, start, length));
            yele = false;
            yList.add(Integer.parseInt(new String(ch, start, length)));
        }
    }

    public List<Integer> getXList()
    {
        return xList;
    }

    public List<Integer> getYList()
    {
        return yList;
    }

};
```

Comment: I Have err report that java.awt.List doesnt take parameter :(

Comment: It's `java.util.List` and not `java.awt.List`. Can you change and check this again?